# Undesired command line completion history

Tags: command-line, wildmenu

Starting `vim` (8.0) with an empty `.vimrc`, or as `vim -u /dev/null`.
Executing:

```
:set nocompatible
:set wildmode=list
```

On the screen:

```
:e .config/█
```

I always thought that what happens when you press `Tab` is the result of my `statusline` or `laststatus`, but changing those do not affect the result:

```
:e .config/
alot/
aurgetrc
aurvote
awesome/
compton.conf
:e .config/█
```

Notice the duplicated `:e .config/` at the top.

The command line is still in the bottom, and what happens next when I type `a` and press `Tab` falls beyond by comprehension:

```
:e .config/
alot/
aurgetrc
aurvote
awesome/
compton.conf
:e .config/a
alot/     aurgetrc  aurvote   awesome/
:e .config/a█
```

It *keeps* the whole command line completion history for each `Tab` press. Further:

```
:e .config/
alot/
aurgetrc
aurvote
awesome/
compton.conf
:e .config/a
alot/     aurgetrc  aurvote   awesome/
:e .config/au
aurgetrc  aurvote
:e .config/au█
```

Needless to say that if I remove `au` hitting `Backspace`, and then press `Tab` again, even more lines are added.

I expect to see command line and wild menu displaying very recent list of completion options when `Tab` is pressed. How can this be done?

```
aurgetrc  aurvote
:e .config/au█
```

Comment: I switched back to `longest,full`. However, I'd like to understand the reasoning of this behavior.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1435), [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/539) and for a fix this [patch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/Cwf7xZAqo9o/3yX1eU8kCgAJ)

Answer (score 1):

Not an entire solution, but I haven't figured out the last part yet.

AFAIK there's no way to clear the screen except by finishing the command or cancelling it. So let's try with a mapping instead:

```
:cnoremap <S-Tab> <C-c>:<Up>
```

This will cancel the current command, clearing the screen, and loading it again in the command line.

**Note**: I tried to also restart the completion with `<Tab>` but the tab char was inserted instead...

Comment: It seems to me that in command line mode completion cease to work if there is colon or angle brackets, and it inserts `^I`.

Comment: Tried to work this around by setting a different `wildchar` to `Z`, it just inserts Z. Changing `<C-c>` to `<Esc>` doesn't help. Changing `<Up>` to `<C-p>` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

In case of someone want to find a solution to avoid the completion history. It just take much time to find this.

Use:

```
set wildmode=longest,full
```

Instead of:

```
set wildmode=longest:list,full
```